# SurfaceView in recyclerview turns black

Tags: android, android-recyclerview, surfaceview

I am using SurfaceView in a ViewHolder to show videos in a RecyclerView. On the first load and without playing videos everything is ok but after scrolling and coming back to videos the SurfaceView is all black. I am not sure if it is an issue with recycling or not. I tried to override the `onViewRecycled` method and release the MediaPlayer or do the `player.setDisplay(null)` but no progress.

Here are the codes:

```
val video = viewHolder.video ?: return
val holder = video.holder

holder.addCallback(object: SurfaceHolder.Callback {
            override fun surfaceChanged(holder: SurfaceHolder, format: Int,
                                        width: Int, height: Int) {}

            override fun surfaceCreated(holder: SurfaceHolder) {
                player.setDisplay(holder)
            }

            override fun surfaceDestroyed(holder: SurfaceHolder) {
                player.setDisplay(null)
                player.release()
            }
        })
```